# Use pseudo selectors in Angular Component?

Tags: html, angular, css-selectors

I created a component with a template containing a div holding the "input"-value and an indicator showing if capslock is active. When I add the Bootstrap `.form-control` class to the host element, it looks pretty much like other input fields except when being focused or disabled.

Is there a way to make use of `:disabled` and other pseudo selectors like `:focus` defined in [Selectors 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#enableddisabled) when creating Angular Components?

I'm stuck with finding a good way to create form components that shares the look and feel of other input components.

Are there other (preferred) ways to make use of input stylings without having to redefine everything?
Would it be better to create a directive and "hack" the template using Renderer2?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but having a template like

```html
<div class="form-control">
    <input type="password" class="custom-input">
</div>
```

try targeting your input with a css class and style it (if you are using scss) with e.g.

```css
.custom-input {
    //some styles
    &:disabled {
        color: grey;
        background: lightgrey;
    }
}
```

If you are using regular css you could do something like

```css
 .custom-input:disabled {
    color: grey;
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: I used this approach in the past, the issue doing this is, that the component won't be usable with other style libraries like Angular Material, etc.

Comment: if you want to use Material, you will be able to target its inner classes and tags by setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` in your `@Component` decorator.

Comment: My goals is to give my components some consistency and use them where ever they fit without having to fiddle each time to style them. Angular material for example adds a layer of complexity using CanDisable interface just to solve the disable. ng-bootstrap solves it by making everything a directive and fiddle them DOM using Renderer2. There should be a more elegant solution, shouldn't it?